# Construct a linear programming problem to maximize the profit below

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, operations-research

The question goes as follows-

> A company makes a specialty solvent at two levels of purity, which it
>   sells in gallon containers. Product $A$ is of higher purity than
>   product $B$, and profits are \$$0.40$/gal on $A$ and \$$0.30$/gal on
>   $B$. **Product $A$ requires twice the processing time of B. If the
>   company produced only $B$, it could make $100$ gal/day**. However,
>   process throughput limitations permit the **production of only $800$
>   gal/day of both $A$ and $B$ combined**. Contract sales require that **at**
>   **least $200$ gal/day of B be produced**.
>  Assuming all of the products
>   can be sold, what volumes of $A$ and $B$ should be produced? Solve
>   using the tableau form of the simplex method. Confirm your solution
>   using graphical means.

I have tried to solve it in the following manner-
Let, $x_1,x_2$ be the volume (in gallon) of $A, B$ to be produced per day
Then we have to **Maximize** $Z=0.4x_1+0.3x_2$
Now, since in together only $800$ gal/day can be produced, we have $x_1+x_2\le800$
Again, since we have to make at least $200$ gal of $B$, we have $x_2\ge200$
From here, I can't proceed. I didn't understand the facts that *$A$ requires twice the processing time of B and if the company produced only $B$, it could make $100$ gal/day*.
What do these statements want to say? Where I will use it?
Can anybody solve this? Thanks for the assistance in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If only $B$ is produced, we would get the maximum number of products of type $B$, then $x_2 \le 100$. Now since $A$ takes twice as long as $B$ to get produced, the maximum products of type $A$ which can be produced will be $50$, or $x_1 \le 50$.

Comment: I don't think so, But it also says that Contract sales require that at least $200$ gal/day of $B$ be produced. And just think if $x_1\le50$ and $x_2\le100$, the given condition " the production of only 800 gal/day of both A and B combined" is irrelevant. Please think twice.

Comment: I see what you mean. Either there is not enough information or the question is wrongly stated. Because clearly the maximum possible production of $B$ would occur when the company solely dedicates to producing $B$, so $x_2$ cannot be more than $100$ gal/day.

Comment: I have seen this problem many books. Even it was solved in Chegg.

Comment: I don’t see how this question makes sense. Can you send me a link to the solution, perhaps?

Comment: https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/company-makes-specialty-solvent-two-levels-purity-itsells-gallon-containers-product-higher-q32744719 . But you can't see it until you subscribe for it, even I can't see.